# Is servlet just like httpHandler in .Net?

Tags: java, asp.net, servlets

Anone can compare those two? Any similarity and difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not Exactly, but you can achieve more and less the same functionality as sync HTTPHandler.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398986.aspx Synchronious vs. Asynchronious

Comment: you mean servlet cannot handle async?

Comment: It can with the version 3.0 JSP specs.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know Servlet is more general purpose you can implement more protocols using it e.g. SIP, other than just http. But it is the basis of all Java serverside web technologies

Comment: But HttpServlet is pretty close.